# show grid by default

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, gridlines

I am using the matplotlib.pyplot package in a Jupyter Notebook and for each separate plot I am turning on the grid:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.grid()
```

Is there a way to show the grid by default, throughout the whole Notebook?

Comment: Yes, you can do this with custom styles: https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html

Comment: This is what I was looking for: `mpl.rcParams.update({"axes.grid" : True)`